# How to count to-many to-many objects in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

Model:
A <-->> B <-->> C

I would like to know how to fetch all A objects that have at least one B object that has at least one C object using the NSPredicate.

If I want to fetch B objects that have at least one C object I would use such predicate.

```
c.@count > 0
```

but to fetch A objects following predicate doesn't work

```
ANY b.c.@count > 0
```

Comment: Have a look at SUBQUERY http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051948/core-data-subquery-predicate

Comment: I have tried to use it but with no luck. Executing SUBQUERY(b, $x, $x.c.@count > 0).@count > 0 fails with error "Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle $x.c.@count"