# How to use NSPredicate to filter objects by the element of their NSSet property in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have two class, one is named `Folder`, the other is named `Entry`.

In my data model, a folder would contain multiple entry, and an entry can be contained by different folders.

So each folder has a `folderID` to identify itself, and a relationship named `entries` which is used to contains `Entry` instances. And each entry has an inverse relationship named `superFolders` which points back to the folder contains it.

Now is my question. Here I get a `folderID`. I want to use this and `NSFetchRequest` to fetch all the `entries` contained by this special folder in Core Data. The following is the main code:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Entry>(entityName: "Entry")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(ANY folder in %K).folderID = %i", #keyPath(Entry.superFolders), folerID)
```

The format string in above code is incorrect, but it mostly explain what I mean. Since `superFolders` property is actually a `NSSet` in Core Data, I can't use `superFolders.folderID == %i` as the judge condition. What exactly I want is to find all the entry whose `superFolder` property contains **any of element** which its `folderID` property match the given `folderID`.

So is that possible to use `NSPredicate` to express what I mean to Core Data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Entry>(entityName: "Entry")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY superFolders.folderID = %@", folderID)
```

See the [NSPredicate reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate)

If you had a more complicated match on the `superFolders` relationship, you would need to use `SUBQUERY`, but in this case a simple `ANY` predicate works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code you provide works perfectly. I find a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051948/core-data-subquery-predicate) and an [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW3) from official document. It's really quite simple.